# Editing files with VIM on Windows under a folder with name starting with + sign

Tags: matlab, vim

I'm using **GVIM** on **Windows 7** editing some MATLAB code. The code is organized as following:

```
.
└── +package
    ├── @class1
    │   └── class1.m
    └── @class2
        └── class2.m
```

When I open GVIM in the current directory, and want to edit the file `class1.m`, usually I'd run the command:

```
:e \+package/@class1/class1.m
```

in GVIM.

This command would work perfectly right on Linux, but on Windows, GVIM created a new buffer  for me with name: `\+package\@class1\class1.m`. (*Note the leading back-slash*.) This is not the file I wanted, and it is not even a legal file name. Apparently, omitting the leading back-slash in the command does not fix this error, either.

I know using the NERD-TREE plugin is a work around, but I'd like to find a way to solve it without any plugin. Could someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading backslash makes Vim treat this as a drive-absolute path. The trick to avoid that is prepending the current directory (`.`) to it:

```
:e .\+package\@class1\class1.m
```